# 2006 Chevy Silverado 5.3 not firing on cylinder 4 and 1

Tags: chevrolet

(Little back story) A month to the day I had my motor replaced. It was a remanufactured motor ran great for that month no issues until my starter got stuck engaged and caught on fire but wasn’t on fire longer than a minute replaced started and ran fine for probably two weeks and then all of a sudden goin down the road it lost power turns out it’s not firing on cylinder 4 and 1. It’s had a new computer put in it I’ve swapped the coils and wires pulled spark plugs swapped them. It’s getting gas because the plugs are wet with gas and it sounds like the two cylinders fire every now and then and burn all the gas at one time they just don’t fire often

Comment: Have you checked if you are getting a spark on those plugs with the plugs removed from the engine?

Comment: I haven’t. The plugs are wet with gas so I assumed they wasn’t getting no spark

Comment: Have you checked fuel pressure and tested the throttle position sensor (TPS) on the throttle plate?

Answer (score 0):

With the symptoms you describe, I think I would start by checking the continuity of the wires that run from the ignition coils back to the ECU and any ground connections as in the wiring diagram.

[image]

You can see the full engine wiring digram [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16OGIA9xDC6b7BifoaE6q3SCgzz5wAnZw/view)

I don’t know if this is the correct diagram for your vehicle, but I presume it will be something similar.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will try it